# How do I solve this error in my code? TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: pandas

How do I eliminate the error below from the given lines of code I have outlined below:
This is the code:

```
    #import the libraries.
     import streamlit as st
     import pandas as pd
     from PIL import Image

     #Display the closing price.
     st.header(company_name+" Close Price\n")
     st.line_chart(df['Close'])
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
     TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Where does `df` come from?

Comment: Check the last time in your code where you did `df = ...`. The value returned by the function is `None`

Comment: If you want a good answer, please add your variable definitions... where you use pandas here, where you use PIL, the only used lib is "streamlit" in your example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DataFrame contains something like:

```
    Id   Open  Close
0  AAA  12.15  13.22
1  BBB  24.11  25.11
```

then `df['Close']` retrieves the respective column and the result is:

```
0    13.22
1    25.11
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

(the left column contains indices and the right column - values from
this column).

But when you run: `df = None` then `df['Close']` yields just the
error you described.

So the probable cause is that your code somehow assigned *None* to *df*.

Maybe you attempted to read *df* from some source and this instruction
resulted in assignment of *None* to *df*.

Note that to get such error *df* variable **must exist**.
Otherwise you would have got another error, namely:
*NameError: name 'df' is not defined*.

How to cope with this: Make sure that *df* contains an actual DataFrame,
with the "wanted" column.